# HTTP Data Collector API vs Logs Ingestion API

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitor

Can someone help me understand the difference between the HTTP Data Collector API vs Logs Ingestion API for ingesting data pipeline logs into azure monitor/azure log analytics workbench?

Which is advised to measure performance of a databricks pipeline?

The following (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/databricks-monitoring/application-logs) is not supported for Azure Databricks 11.0 (Spark 3.3.0).

Comment: it would be great if you provide more details like what you tried and where you are getting blockers then only community members can help you.

Comment: I added more information.

Answer (score 0):

The [HTTP Data Collector API (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-collector-api?tabs=powershell) is the oldest method of injecting Log data into a Log Analytics Workspace.

With this API you can submit payload to the workspace without even predefining the table schema, it uses the workspaceId and sharedKey to create an authentication signature

Strangely enough, it never came out of preview.

More recently the [Logs Ingestion API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/logs-ingestion-api-overview) got released (GA).

This method is using a Data Callection Endpoint, Data Collection rule to inject (an even possibly transform) the data in a table that has to be predefined in the the Log Analytics Workspace.

In **my opinion**, the [HTTP Data Collector API (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-collector-api?tabs=powershell) is going to be deprecated eventually due to the availability of the [Logs Ingestion API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/logs-ingestion-api-overview).
*This is **not** officially announced by Microsoft !*

Comment: Thank you for this. What do you recommend using to send custom logs for databricks jobs pipelines being deployed from Azure devops to az monitor/log analytics workbench? I built a proof of concept using the HTTP Data Collector API but if it's not future-proof then it's not worth pursuing.

Comment: I would personally go for the "Log Ingestion API". Slightly harder to implement, but looks more future-proof.

Answer (score 0):

The note in documentation is misleading - it wasn't updated after recent changes.  The PR to support DBR 11+ did exist for a some time, and ~2 weeks it was merged into a separate branch with name `l4jv2` ([link](https://github.com/mspnp/spark-monitoring/tree/l4jv2)) - you can build from that branch build for DBR versions 11 and higher.

Comment: Thank you. May I please ask if you can point me towards documentation on how to implement this. I am trying to learn how to do this properly but I do not have the knowledge yet.

Comment: Just follow instructions in the README